# Segfault on FD_ISSET

Tags: c++, sockets, unix, select

I've run into a rather strange problem:

I use `select()` in order to determine if a socket becomes readable. However, whenever a client connects, I get a segfault when I call `FD_ISSET()` to check if a given socket is present in the `fd_set`.

```
/* [...] */

while( /* condition */ ){

    timeout.tv_sec = 0;
    timeout.tv_usec = SELECT_TIMEOUT;

    //this simply fills sockets with some file descriptors (passed in by clients - both parameters are passed by reference)
    maxfd = this->build_fd_set( clients, sockets );

    //wait until something relevant happens
    readableCount = select( maxfd + 1, &sockets, (fd_set*)NULL, (fd_set*)NULL, &timeout );

    if( readableCount > 0 ){
        //Some sockets have become readable

         printf( "\nreadable: %d, sockfd: %d, maxfd: %d\n",
                readableCount, this->sockfd, maxfd );

        //Check if listening socket has pending connections
        // SEGFAULT OCCURS HERE
        if( FD_ISSET( this->sockfd, &sockets ) ) {

            DBG printf( "new connection incoming" );

            this->handle_new_connection( clients );

            /* [...] */
        }else {
            // Data is pending on some socket
            /* [...] */
        }
    }else if( readableCount < 0 ) {
        //An error occured
        /* [...] */
        return;
    }else {
        // select has timed out
        /* [...] */
    }

}
```

**EDIT:**
Yeah, sorry for the sparse info: I've updated the code.

`this->sock_fd` is set up to be a descriptor for a listening socket, created using`this->sockfd = socket( AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM, 0 );` and then made listening via `listen( this->sockfd, ACCEPT_BACKLOG )`.

build_fd_set:

```
int SvcServer::build_fd_set( const vector<int>& clients, fd_set& sockets ) {

    //build up the socket set
    FD_ZERO( &sockets );
    FD_SET( this->sockfd, &sockets ); //listening socket is always part of the set

    int maxfd = this->sockfd;
    //Add all currently connected sockets to the list
    for( vector<int>::const_iterator it = clients.begin() ; it != clients.end() ; ++it )     {
        FD_SET( *it, &sockets );
        maxfd = max( maxfd, *it );
    }

    return maxfd;
}
```

It really doesn't matter what `clients` is, it' just empty and meant to be filled once clients connect, which is not happening since the whole thing segfaults on the first incoming connection.

Also, here's some sample output:

```
readable: 1, sockfd: 3, maxfd: 3
Segmentation fault
```

The things I can derive here are:

- The call to `select()` works, `readable` is set correctly
- Also `sockfd` and `maxfd` are valid descriptors.

I'm afraid I can't provide you with any debugging info (e.g. gdb) since I'm cross compiling and gdb is not available on the platform I'm compiling to.

Comment: what is the `build_fd_set` method? and where is `sockets` declared/initialized?

Comment: What happens to this->sockfd?

Comment: What is `sockets`? How do you initialize it?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You haven't mentioned what debugging or investigation you've done for this problem, so I assume the question you meant to ask (since you didn't actually ask one) was how to use the debugger to diagnose this kind of problem. If you're just asking people to find the problem in your specific code, then it's not really a good fit for Stack Overflow, where questions are supposed to be useful for future visitors, too.

Comment: `DBG` is defined to be `if(1)`  if `DEBUG` is defined - `if(0)` otherwise, ugly I know, but this is more of a quick hack to test some things out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, I figured it out. * **stupid me** *

Turns out, the segfault was never actually occuring at the suspected position, the last printf before the segfault never got shown because it stdout wasn't flushed. The actual segfault occured a little later and was (of course) my mistake.

thx nevertheless